# Filter added items to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks, state

In my App Im adding new items to array and I want filter those new. But if I .filter by state it modify my original array and I cant filter from the beginning (original array). I tried filter using this.props.productsToFilter then it works it filter products but it doesnt see new one which I add.

I tried to setState if my component is render but it goes into infinity loop.

**App**

```
import produkty from "./common/consts/produkty";

function App() {
  const [productsToBuy, setProductsToBuy] = useState([]);
  const [productsList, setProductsList] = useState(produkty);

  return (
    <div className={styles.appWrapper}>
      <AddProducts sendNewProductToParent={setProductsList} />
      <ProductsFilters
        productsToFilter={productsList}
        sendFilteredNazwaToParentComponent={setProductsList}
      />
      <div className={styles.columnsWrapper}>
        <ProductsList
          newProductsList={productsList}
          sendAddedProductsToParent={setProductsToBuy}
        />
        <ShopingList productsToBuy={productsToBuy} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**ProdFilter**

```
class ProductsFilters extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productsToFilter: this.props.productsToFilter,
      searchPhrase: ``,
      searchCategory: ``,
      searchOnlyGroceries: false,
    };

    this.filterProducts = this.filterProducts.bind(this);
    this.uniqueCategory = this.uniqueCategory.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.productsToFilter !== this.props.productsToFilter) {
      this.setState({
        productsToFilter: this.props.productsToFilter,
      });
    }
    console.log(`test`);
  }

  //////// FILTER ////////

  filterProducts = () => {
    // FILTER BY PHRASE //
    let filteredProducts = this.state.productsToFilter.filter((currProduct) =>
      currProduct.nazwa.includes(this.state.searchPhrase.toLowerCase())
    );
    // FILTER BY GROCERIES //
    if (this.state.searchOnlyGroceries) {
      filteredProducts = this.state.productsToFilter.filter(
        (currProduct) => currProduct.produktSpozywczy
      );
    }
    // FILTER BY CATEGORY //
    if (this.state.searchCategory) {
      filteredProducts = this.state.productsToFilter.filter(
        (currProduct) => currProduct.kategoria === this.state.searchCategory
      );
    }

    this.props.sendFilteredNazwaToParentComponent(filteredProducts);
  };

  //////// FILTER BY PHRASE ////////

  handleSearchPhraseChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ searchPhrase: event.target.value }, () =>
      this.filterProducts()
    );
  };

  //////// FILTER BY CATEGORY ////////

  handleSelectCategory = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ searchCategory: event.target.value }, () =>
      this.filterProducts()
    );
  };

  uniqueCategory = () => {
    const categoryList = this.state.productsToFilter.map((currCategory) => {
      return currCategory.kategoria;
    });
    const uniqueCategoryEl = [...new Set(categoryList)];
    return uniqueCategoryEl;
  };

  //////// FILTER BY CHECKBOX GROCERIES////////

  handleOnlyGroceriesChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ searchOnlyGroceries: event.target.checked }, () =>
      this.filterProducts()
    );
  };

  render() {
    const uniqueCategoryList = this.uniqueCategory();
    return (
      <div className={styles.Wrapper}>
        <p>Products Filters</p>
        <br />
        <input
          value={this.state.searchPhrase}
          onChange={this.handleSearchPhraseChange}
        ></input>
        <button onClick={this.filterProducts}>Search</button>
        <br />
        <p>Filter by category</p>
        <select onChange={this.handleSelectCategory}>
          {uniqueCategoryList.map((currCategory) => (
            <option key={currCategory} value={currCategory}>
              {currCategory}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />
        <p>Filter by groceries</p>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={this.handleOnlyGroceriesChange}
          value={this.state.searchOnlyGroceries}
        ></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductsFilters;
```

**AddProducts**

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import styles from "../../common/styles/Headers.module.scss";

function AddProducts(props) {
  const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState({
    productName: ``,
    category: ``,
    groceries: false,
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNewProduct({
      ...newProduct,
      [event.target.name]:
        event.target.type === "checkbox"
          ? event.target.checked
          : event.target.value,
    });
  }

  function handleAddNewProduct() {
    const addProduct = [
      {
        nazwa: newProduct.productName,
        kategoria: newProduct.category,
        produktSpozywczy: newProduct.groceries,
      },
    ];
    props.sendNewProductToParent((listOfPrimiaryProducts) => [
      ...listOfPrimiaryProducts,
      ...addProduct,
    ]);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.Wrapper}>
      <p>Add products</p>
      <input
        name="productName"
        value={newProduct.productName}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        name="category"
        value={newProduct.category}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <input
        name="groceries"
        type="checkbox"
        value={newProduct.groceries}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <p>Is it groceries?</p>
      <button onClick={handleAddNewProduct}>Add new product</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddProducts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 states to represent:

1. The full list of products (including newly added items)
2. The filtered list of products

Then your `ProductsFilters` component takes the full list in, and outputs (via setter) the filtered list.

For example:

```
function App() {
  const [productsToBuy, setProductsToBuy] = useState([]);

  const [fullProductsList, setFullProductsLidt] = useState(produkty);
  const [filteredProductsList, setFilteredProductsList] = useState(fullProductList); // In case initial state does not filter out anything

  return (
    <>
      <AddProducts
        // Add new items into the full list, so that they are processed by the filter stage later on
        sendNewProductToParent={setFullProductsList}
      />
      <ProductsFilters
        // Take the full list in
        productsToFilter={fullProductsList}
        // Store the output into the filtered list
        sendFilteredNazwaToParentComponent={setFilteredProductsList}
      />
      <div>
        <ProductsList
          // Display the filtered list
          newProductsList={filteredProductsList}
          sendAddedProductsToParent={setProductsToBuy}
        />
        <ShopingList productsToBuy={productsToBuy} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It this approach I think that fullProductList only updates at the beginning. I my app I want to add new products after filter some times.

Comment: Have you tried it? What makes you think it will not update?

Comment: Yes, the list of products which I import appears without problems. After I enter new one andd add to list, it doesn't appear.

Comment: I strongly suspect an issue in how you implemented it, but without a [mcve], it is almost impossible to help you further.

Comment: I have updated my post and I've added component which add products. Maybe sth here is wrong.